# JSON.stringify from typescript/javascript do not match json-String param/request-body in Java controller

Tags: java, json, angularjs, typescript, rest

I am using jdk 1.8. I have a rest end point in java controller as :

```
@PostMapping("/filters")
public ResponseEntity<StatsDTO> listWithFilter(
      @RequestBody(required = false) String filter
) {
try { 
   ...............
}
}
```

Test snippet against above controller is passing (getting back expected result in this snippet) as :

```
@Test
public void findReferralTest15() throws IOException {

   String result = webClient.post()
        .uri(endpoint(helper.entity + "/filters"))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, clientUser())
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(buildJsonForQuery15()))
        .exchange()
        .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        .expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectBody(String.class).returnResult().getResponseBody();


   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   ResponseList referralList = mapper.readValue(result, ResponseList.class);
} 

public String buildJsonForQuery15() {
    String json = "{\"billType\":{\"INTAKE\":true}}";
    return json;
}
```

Now when I am trying to integrate with front end (Angular 7 on typescript), I have to do JSON.stringify **twice** **(to a json object or filter to be submitted as requestbody)** to make it work with the back end. I am getting **null** otherwise as the value of the **"filter"** ( in the request body) at the java controller end.

So with **double** JSON.stringify submitted result from our front end is **(WHEN IT WORKS)**:

```
"{\"billType\":{\"INTAKE\":true}}"
```

So with **single** JSON.stringify submitted result from our from end is **(WHEN IT DOESN'T WORK)**:

```
{"billType":{"INTAKE":true}}
```

**Question : What should be the data type of requestBody **"filter"**, in the java controller,  to make it work with single JSON.stringify?**

I tried **json.org.JsonObject** as datatype for "filter" but it did not make any difference.

Thanks in advance.

**Front end snippet:**

```
const fullUrl = `${this.referralsUrl}/filters?first=${first}&max=${max}`;
const headerDict = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
};
const headers = new HttpHeaders(headerDict);

 if (filters) {

  const requestBody = JSON.stringify(filters);
  return this.http
    .post<Page<ClinAssistReferral>>(fullUrl, JSON.stringify(requestBody), { headers })
    .pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
      ...........
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the body is not dynamic, making a DTO for the request is preferred.

If body is dynamic, I would suggest you to try `JsonNode` from jackson. See if this library can

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
...

@PostMapping("/filters")
public ResponseEntity<StatsDTO> listWithFilter(
      @RequestBody(required = false) JsonNode filter
) {
   try { 
      var intake = filter.get("billType").get("INTAKE").asBoolean()
      ...............
   }
}
```